# Dynamically adding events to FullCalendar in Ember component

Tags: ember.js, fullcalendar

I have successfully wrapped the full calendar plugin in an ember component, and I am able to display event data that is initially provided by the controller. I am wondering if it is possible to add events to the calendar based on user actions. So far my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Here is a bin that replicates my current situation --> [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yemogiyi/1/edit)

You can see in the bin that when the user clicks the button the new event object is successfully pushed to the event array that is populating the calendar. Now how can I get the calendar to update to reflect this new event? I have tried `addEventSource` and `refetchEvents` to no avail.

**EDIT For clarity:** The functioning implementation in the provided jsbin does add the event but it is not visible on the calendar until the user clicks to a different month and then back to the month where the event was added. I am trying to have the event show on the calendar immediately after it is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kakigoori provided the correct command to use, however it needs to be passed the event that is being added not the full array of events which was producing undesired side effects.

I have updated the jsBin to show a working example of the desired functionality which can be found below.

Solution --> [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yemogiyi/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation for FullCalendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

You need to do `.fullCalendar('renderEvent', this.get('events'), true);` in order to actually render additions.

You may also consider using the [Ember.Component Events](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_didInsertElement) in order to cleanly handle what is going on when your jQuery plugin takes over the element.

You should also use this.$ to confine the elements that you may be selecting from, to limit what you get into what's inside of your component.